# Implementing a "like" operator multiple times in one Linq to Entities query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, expression, sql-like

We have a list of strings and we need to filter our results by that list.  Example would be find all students who have SSNs that start with 465, 496, or 497 (plus x more)

```
List<string> list = GetPossibleStartsWithValues();
var qry = from student in entities.Students.WhereStartsWith(x=>x.SSN, list)
select new SearchedStudent
{
    Name = student.Name,
    SSN = student.SSN,
    ...
}
```

The code provided [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/) is close to what we need, but we can't figure out how to impliment the StartsWith that we need using the Expression Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could *try* this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereStartsWith<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
    Expression<Func<T, string>> projection,
    List<T> list)
{
    return source.Where(x => list.Any(y => projection(x).StartsWith(y)));
}
```

That may well not work, but it would be worth trying before you go into anything more complicated.

EDIT: As you say, the above won't compile - you basically need to build an expression tree representing the bit within the `Where` clause. Oops. However, before you start doing that, it would be worth seeing whether it'll work in the end. Try this:

```
List<string> list = GetPossibleStartsWithValues();
var qry = from student in entities.Students
     .Where(student => list.Any(y => student.SSN.StartsWith(y)))
select new SearchedStudent
{
    Name = student.Name,
    SSN = student.SSN,
    ...
}
```

If that doesn't work, then making a more general method won't be any use :(

Comment: I cant get the code to compile. I get the error 'projection' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'. What do I need to change?

Comment: @johnnywhoop: Oops. Will fix when I get home.

Comment: Yeah that worked. Would creating an Expression make it faster? It seems pretty slow but it is usable.

Comment: @johnnywhoop: Have a look at the generated SQL. "Seems pretty slow" isn't very exact... without looking at the SQL you can't really tell what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a compound statement such as

```
var qry = from student in entities.Students.Where( 
             s => list.Where( x => s.StartsWith(x)).Count() != 0 )
```