# Can I do multiple ".Contains" tests in a single Linq-to-SQL statement?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a requirement to return all of the items that match one of a list of strings. The user enters a list of semi-colon separated strings:

> abc; mno; xyz

and I need to return all the items who's product code (for example) contains either "abc" OR "mno" OR "xyz".

I have the following code which works for one case, correctly returning the expected items in `allItems`:

```
IQueryable<Items> allItems = FindItemsBasedOnSomeOtherCriteria();
var productCodes = inputString.Split(new char[] { ';', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
IEnumerable<Item> results = null;

foreach (var productCode in productCodes)
{
    var query = allItems.Where(i => i.ProductCode.ToLower().Contains(productCode.ToLower()));

    if (results == null)
    {
        results = query;
    }
    else
    {
        results = results.Union(query);
    }
}

allItems = results.AsQueryable();
```

However, in another case I need to post-process the list. This uses `allItems` as one of the inputs to another query.

When I have nothing or only a single entry in `inputString` the post-processing code works fine. However, if I have a list of items I get the following exception raised:

> An IQueryable that returns a self-referencing Constant expression is not supported.

It's the `Union` statement that's causing the problem. So how can I rewrite the above loop so it doesn't require it?

Ideally I'd like to be able to write something like:

```
var productCodes = inputString.ToLower().Split(new char[] { ';', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var query = allItems.Where(i => productCodes.InverseContains(i.ProductCode.ToLower()));
```

but that doesn't exist.

The search is throwing up this question:

> [Linq-to-SQL: Combining (OR'ing) multiple "Contains" filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501329/linq-to-sql-combining-oring-multiple-contains-filters)

which is asking the same thing, but the accepted answer is just a link to a 3<sup>rd</sup> party toolkit.

I've tried other constructs including now the one suggested by CodeCaster and either they give the same error or this one:

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

For reference that code is:

```
var result = allItems.Where(i => productCodes.Any(p => i.ProductCode.ToLower().Contains(p)));
```

Comment: You can try `allItems.Where(i => productCodes.Any(p => i.ProductCode.ToLower().Contains(p)))`, but I don't know whether that can be translated to a store expression.

Comment: Seems to be similar to this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660557/implementing-a-like-operator-multiple-times-in-one-linq-to-entities-query

Comment: @RobH - indeed it does - That one didn't show up in my search either :(

Comment: Does @CodeCaster's suggestion work? It seems like it should...

Comment: @CodeCaster - that gives and exception of "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator."

Comment: I was afraid so. Then you'll have to build an expression that can be simplified to `Where(i => i.Contains(p[0]) || i.Contains(p[1]) || ...)`, which can in turn be translated to SQL. You can do the building using the PredicateBuilder shown in the linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible with basic LINQ-to-SQL. The already accepted answer in the other question is indeed the correct way to do it.

The PredicateBuilder and the mentioned LINQKit is open source and can simply be used within your project without any problems. It is also available as [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/) which makes usage even simpler within your project.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I was going to mark this as a duplicate once I'd had chance to check out the PredicateBuilder.